# How Create Paths From Given Nodes with no destination

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have found the possible moves of the piece and stored into following array.

```
var moves = [ {from: 67 , to:35} , {from: 35 , to:3} , {from: 35 , to:37} , {from: 35 , to:33} , {from: 37 , to:5} , {from: 37 , to:39} , {from: 33 , to:1} ,{from: 39 , to:7} ] ;
```

Now I need to create the following paths from these moves.

```
var path1= [{from:67, to:35} , {from:35, to:3}];
var path2= [{from:67, to:35} , {from:35, to:37} ,  {from:37, to:5} ];
var path3= [{from:67, to:35} , {from:35, to:33} ,  {from:33, to:1}];
var path4= [{from:67, to:35} , {from:35, to:37} ,  {from:37, to:39} ,  {from:39, to:7} ];
```

I did some code to create an array of paths but it didn't the work I need to, could someone please help to create the paths.

I can't use DFS or BFS because I have no destination point.

```
function GetPaths(moves,possiblePaths) {
    var paths = [];
    var allmoves=[];
    for (var x = 0 ; x < moves.length ; x++) {
        var path = [];
        var move = [];
        var data2 = [];
        data2.push([moves[x].from, moves[x].to]);
        for (var y = x + 1 ; y < moves.length ; y++) {
            if (moves[x].to == moves[y].from) {

                if (!(path.includes(data2[0]))) {
                    path.push(data2[0]);
                    move.push(moves[x]);
                }
                var data = [moves[y].from, moves[y].to];
                path.push(data);
                move.push(moves[y]);
            }
        }
        if (path.length > 0) paths.push(path);
        if (move.length > 0) {
            allmoves.push(move);
        }



    }
    if (paths.length>1) {

    var newpaths = [];
    var newmoves =[];
    var nextRow = paths[0];
    var nextmove = allmoves[0];
    var len = paths.length;


    for (var h = 1 ; h < nextRow.length; h++) {

        for (var j = 1 ; j < len ; j++) {
            var newpath = [];
            var newmove =[];
            if (isInArray(nextRow[h], paths[j][0])) {

                newpath.push(nextRow[0]);
                 newmove.push(nextmove[0]);
                var nextfound = false;
                for (var k = j + 1 ; k < paths.length ; k++) {
                    if (isInArray(paths[j][paths[j].length - 1], paths[k][0])) {
                        newpath.push(paths[j][0]);
                        if (paths[k][0][0] - paths[k][0][1] != -(paths[k][1][0] - paths[k][1][1])) {
                            newpath.push(paths[k]);
                            newmove.push(allmoves[k]);
                        } else {
                            newpath.push(paths[k][0]);
                            newmove.push(allmoves[k][0]);
                        }

                        nextfound = true;
                    }

                }
                if (!nextfound) {
                    newpath.push(paths[j]);
                    newmove.push(allmoves[j]);
                }

            }
            if (newpath.length > 0) {
                newpaths.push(newpath);
                newmoves.push(newmove);
            }
        }

    }

    return newmoves;
    }
    return allmoves;
}
```

The below Answer works for the above example, but doesn't work for the below example

84 to 52 , 52 to 20 , 52 to 54 , 52 to 50 , 20 to 22 , 20 to 18 , 54 to 22
50 to 18 , 22 to 20 , 18 to 20 , 20 to 18 , 20 to 22

which has the following paths

1) 84 52 , 52 20 , 20 18

2) 84 52 , 52 20 , 20 22

3) 84 52 , 52 54 , 54 22 , 22 20 , 20 18

4) 84 52 , 52 50 , 50 18 , 18 20 , 20 22

Graph for this.

[image]

Comment: What if there are recursive paths? Do the paths always start from the first array item?

Comment: @MattWay no in this case it only starts from the first item and there are no recursive paths and it is not necessary that all paths contain the first item

Comment: You say that in this case it only starts from the first item, but then say it is not necessary that all paths contain the first item. Can you give an example that shows the second case?

Comment: @MattWay same example  just remove the first item
var moves = [  {from: 35 , to:3} , {from: 35 , to:37} , {from: 35 , to:33} , {from: 37 , to:5} , {from: 37 , to:39} , {from: 33 , to:1} ,{from: 39 , to:7} ] ;

var path1= [ {from:35, to:3}];
var path2= [{from:35, to:37} ,  {from:37, to:5} ];
var path3= [ {from:35, to:33} ,  {from:33, to:1}];
var path4= [ {from:35, to:37} ,  {from:37, to:39} ,  {from:39, to:7} ];

Comment: @MattWay well in short if can find just longest path that would be great but I have another function which can return the largest path from the given paths but I am stuck to find all possible paths

Comment: @MattWay the above question is update could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is a [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) problem: find every path given a root to all of its leaves (descendant nodes that have no children).

To perform the traversal, it helps to put the tree in a form that enables quick lookup of children given a parent. After the search, we'll need to transform the resulting paths into the format you've requested.

Here's the tree:

```
     67
     |
     35
   / | \  
  3  37 33
    / \   \
   5   39  1
        \
         7
```

The solution is the same as a DFS/BFS, except instead of returning once a leaf node is found, compute its path back to the root, add it to the master path list and keep searching the rest of the tree.

```js
const pathsToLeaves = (root, tree) => {
  const parent = {root: null};
  const stack = [root];
  const paths = [];
  
  while (stack.length) {
    let curr = stack.pop();
    
    if (curr in tree) {
      for (const child of tree[curr]) {
        stack.push(child);
        parent[child] = curr;
      }
    }
    else {
      const path = [];
      
      while (curr) {
        path.unshift(curr);
        curr = parent[curr];
      }
      
      paths.push(path);
    }
  }
  
  return paths;
};


const movesToTree = moves => 
  moves.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (!(e.from in a)) {
      a[e.from] = [];
    }

    a[e.from].push(e.to);
    return a;
  }, {})
;

const pathsToMoves = paths => 
  paths.map(f => f.reduce((a, e, i) => {
    if (a === null) {
      a = [{from: e}];
    }
    else if (i < f.length - 1) {
      a[a.length-1].to = e;
      a.push({from: e});
    }
    else {
      a[a.length-1].to = e;
    }

    return a;
  }, null))
;

const getPaths = (from, moves) => 
  pathsToMoves(pathsToLeaves(from, movesToTree(moves)))
;

const moves = [
  {from: 67, to: 35}, 
  {from: 35, to: 3}, 
  {from: 35, to: 37}, 
  {from: 35, to: 33}, 
  {from: 37, to: 5}, 
  {from: 37, to: 39}, 
  {from: 33, to: 1},
  {from: 39, to: 7}
]; 

console.log(getPaths(67, moves));
```

The second example you've posted is a cyclic multigraph. It's still possible to get all of the paths you've requested, but the algorithm is a lot less efficient than the tree version due to preprocessing to remove parallel edges in the multigraph, conversion to/from the desired format and array/object copying during the traversal. Many of these speed bumps can be optimized away using various approaches, but here's a basic version:

```js
const pathsFrom = (src, graph) => {
  const stack = [[src, [], {}]];
  const paths = [];
  
  while (stack.length) {
    const [curr, path, visited] = stack.pop();
    
    if (curr in graph && !(curr in visited)) {
      visited[curr] = 1;
      path.push(curr);
      let pathFollowed = false;

      for (const neighbor of graph[curr]) {
        if (!(neighbor in visited)) {
          pathFollowed = true;

          const visitedCpy = Object.keys(visited).reduce((a, e) => {
            a[e] = visited[e];
            return a;
          }, {});
          stack.push([neighbor, path.slice(0), visitedCpy]);
        }
      }

      if (!pathFollowed) {
        paths.push(path);
      }
    }
    else {
      paths.push(path.concat(curr));
    }
  }
  
  return paths;
};

const movesToGraph = moves => 
  moves.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (!(e.from in a)) {
      a[e.from] = [];
    }

    a[e.from].push(e.to);
    return a;
  }, {})
;

const pathsToMoves = paths => 
  paths.map(f => f.reduce((a, e, i) => {
    if (a === null) {
      a = [{from: e}];
    }
    else if (i < f.length - 1) {
      a[a.length-1].to = e;
      a.push({from: e});
    }
    else {
      a[a.length-1].to = e;
    }

    return a;
  }, null))
;

const dedupe = a =>
  Object.values(a.reduce((a, e) => {
    const key = `${e.from} ${e.to}`;

    if (!(key in a)) {
      a[key] = e;
    }

    return a;
  }, {}))
;

const getPaths = (from, moves) => 
  pathsToMoves(pathsFrom(from, movesToGraph(dedupe(moves)), [], []))
;

[
  [
    {from: 67, to: 35}, 
    {from: 35, to: 3}, 
    {from: 35, to: 37}, 
    {from: 35, to: 33}, 
    {from: 37, to: 5}, 
    {from: 37, to: 39}, 
    {from: 33, to: 1},
    {from: 39, to: 7}
  ],
  [
    {from: 84, to: 52}, 
    {from: 52, to: 20}, 
    {from: 52, to: 54}, 
    {from: 52, to: 50}, 
    {from: 20, to: 22}, 
    {from: 20, to: 18}, 
    {from: 54, to: 22},
    {from: 50, to: 18},
    {from: 22, to: 20},
    {from: 18, to: 20},
    {from: 20, to: 18},
    {from: 20, to: 22},
  ]
].forEach(test => console.log(getPaths(test[0].from, test)));
```

Comment: this doesn't work for this move
84 to 52 , 52 to 20 , 52 to 54 , 52 to 50 , 20 to 22 , 20 to 18 , 54 to 22
50 to 18 , 22 to 20 , 18 to 20 , 20 to 18 , 20 to 22

Comment: Seems like you're moving the goalpost. You posted a tree and you're now asking for a cyclic graph. Is that the actual question or are you planning on changing your requirements? Above, in a comment, you said "no in this case it only starts from the first item and there are no recursive paths".

Comment: yeah I said because I was wrong and I didn't thought the edge from a path can be negative. the piece can only move in forward direction not in reverse so that's why I said there isn't recursive path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "positive" and "negative" edges, you'll need to clarify that. Please use graph terminology; are you talking about directed edges? If you have directed edges `20 -> 18` and `18 -> 20`, that's an endless, recursive cycle. A cyclic graph is a totally different structure than a tree, which has no cycles and requires different algorithms. In your example, you also have `20 -> 18` listed twice--why? How can I update my answer to take into account new information if you're planning on changing it again? Please do a final and complete clarification to your question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, and yeah I need cyclic graph and I have attached the image of the graph in question.

Comment: the question has now complete clarity can you please update your answer?

Comment: I have a basic algorithm, but I found more paths (6) in the graph than you listed. `84>52>50>18>20, 84>52>50>18>20>22, 84>52>54>22>20>18, 84>52>54>22>20, 84>52>20>18, 84>52>20>22`. Does this sound accurate? Also, how large is the graph you plan to run this on? I'm not sure if my algorithm is as efficient as it could be.

Comment: Also, your updated graph is a [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph), with `20->18` and `20->22` each listed twice. If you want to include those parallel edges, I calculate 12 paths. Please confirm whether the graph is a multigraph or if this is was a typo. Let's take discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180645/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-engr-umair).